# OpenWRT in home router

Tags: router, openwrt

I decided to flash the router with the OpenWRT firmware. Compound I is for PPTP, and of the " box " is not supported by the PPTP . Is set with the casting packets to the router , but the installation error . How to actually solve?

```
root@OpenWrt:/# opkg install kmod-pptp_3.18.17-1_ar71xx.ipk
Installing kmod-pptp (3.18.17-1) to root...
Collected errors:
 * satisfy_dependencies_for: Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for kmod-                                                                                                                     pptp:
 *      kernel (= 3.18.17-1-5dcb66d04a38219f7fd91c748f0e9a32) *         kmod-gre                                                                                                                      *
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package kmod-pptp.
```

Comment: Your  post is not easy to understand. If you have troubles with English, you should at least try an automatic translator, like Google's: https://translate.google.com#de|en| It is not perfect, but it can still offer some improvement.

Answer (score 2):

The package you downloaded is for a different version of OpenWrt. You can see which version you have installed by looking at the login message or `/etc/openwrt_release`. It looks like this:

```
DISTRIB_ID="OpenWrt"
DISTRIB_RELEASE="14.07"
DISTRIB_REVISION="r42625"
DISTRIB_CODENAME="barrier_breaker"
DISTRIB_TARGET="ar71xx/generic"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="OpenWrt Barrier Breaker 14.07"
DISTRIB_TAINTS=""
```

You can then go to `https://downloads.openwrt.org/$DISTRIB_CODENAME/$DISTRIB_RELEASE/$DISTRIB_TARGET/packages` (in this example: `https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ar71xx/generic/packages/`) to get a package that is compatible with your setup.

To easily get the URL, you can use the following commands:

```
source /etc/openwrt_release
echo https://downloads.openwrt.org/$DISTRIB_CODENAME/$DISTRIB_RELEASE/$DISTRIB_TARGET/packages
```